# How to show related parent's child records in lookup field in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object Customer/Agency which has two lookup fields Agency(to Account) and Agency Contact(to Contact). When a user selects an account in Agency field I need to show the related contacts in Agency Contact field during the creation of a record or after the record is saved. How is it possible using the standard functionality of Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, typically new/edit screens like that are hard to modify and you might end up having to write something custom.

- look into lookup filters. Maybe you can tie these 2 lookups so 2nd one displays only contacts linked to 'this' account. It's not perfect, you'd still need to search for contact's name which takes minimum 2 characters and can get annoying but oh well
- after it's saved, if you use Lightning Experience, you can edit the Lightning Page layout and drop a standalone related list. Make it be based on account lookup, not on current record's id and pick contacts rel. list. It's bit "pro", gets you bit closer to Console Page Layouts but would work. That's only after save though.
- You could try with low code solution called "visual flow" or a full-blown code component
- does the business process have to start standalone? What if you make it start from Contact's record. Have it prepopulate Contact and Account automatically. Either from normal related list's "New" button or with a "quick action" so you can decide which fields are most important, what to prepopulate... It's bit of annoyance, a change in the business process but if it means less searching and staying closer to standard...